# Why does new-object -com excel.application not return a System.__ComObject object?

Tags: powershell, com

When I create an `excel.application` and a `scripting.fileSystemObject` COM object with Powershell...

```
PS C:\> $xls = new-object -com excel.application
PS C:\> $fso = new-object -com scripting.fileSystemObject
```

... I get a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass` ...

```
PS C:\> $xls.GetType().FullName
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
```

... and a `System.__ComObject` object:

```
PS C:\> $fso.GetType().FullName
System.__ComObject
```

I am wondering where the PowerShell runtime environment gets the information from that it is supposed to return a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass` object.

Comment: Office comes with a bunch of Primary Interop Assemblies (PIA) that provide “official” wrappers around certain COM classes to make them easier to use from .Net. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa302338(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#what-is-a-pia for more info...